# How to hide menu item in navigation from users who have no permissions to view the page?

Tags: 2013, permissions, hidden, unique, managed-navigation

I have a menu item in my subsite menu (it is a term driven menu, so managed navigation) that links to a page with unique permissions. Only certain users have been given permissions to see the page and to edit it.

**Let's say that person X and person Y have been given permissions to access this page and person Z doesn't have any permissions for this page at all. Page B is the page with the unique permissions.**

This is the subsite menu that person X and Y see:

```
Page A
Page B
Page C
Page D
```

And this is the subsite menu that person Z *should* see:

```
Page A
Page C
Page D
```

However currently person Z can still see page B in the subsite menu, but upon clicking that menu item linked to page B, person Z will get a "You have no access to this page". I want person Z to not see that menu item at all, person Z shouldn't see page B in the menu.

**I want the menu item to be hidden if the user has no permissions for the page behind that menu item.**

How exactly can I achieve this? 
I've been searching all day and I just can't figure it out, to me it seems that this should be default behavior that a page isn't listed in the navigation when the user has no permissions to access it (be it reading, editing, contributing,.. doesn't matter).

*Any help is greatly appreciated!!!*

**EDIT**
The answer to this question can be found [here](http://sharingtothepoint.blogspot.be/2013/12/how-to-hide-links-in-navigation-from.html). It is quite long, please check the link for all the detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might suffice your requirements. I had to remove the settings buttons based on user privilege. So, I went ahead doing this.

```
if (belongsToGroup == true) 
{
    $('#suiteBarButtons').hide();
}
```

By using .hide() property you can disable the option in a way.

Comment: How exactly did you check if a user belonged to a group? The var belongsToGroup, how did you define it?
I was thinking about getting all members of a group and put them in an array, and then check if the current user was in that array. If he/she was in the array, it would do nothing. If he/she wasn't, the link should be hidden. But I haven't even gotten to the part on fetching all the members of a certain group... So I was wondering how you did it.

Comment: @Magali You can create multiple SharePoint groups. Define client context and web, using which you can retrieve the groups `var user = web.get_currentUser();
 this.usergrps = user.get_groups(); clientContext.Load(this.usergrps);`

Comment: Ok so, I have 'website' instead of 'web', and now I added  `clientContext.load(website,'EffectiveBasePermissions');`.
In the function onRequestSucceeded, I added this to check the permissions:  
`if (website.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems)) {
 //User Has Edit Permissions
  alert('YEAH, edit list permissions!');
 } 
 else { alert('Boo, no edit list permissions!'); }`
Thanks! Now I get it and it works, I just have to replace the alerts with the ID or class of the menu item and hide it. :)